# serving static files from jwilder/nginx-proxy

Tags: docker, docker-compose, static-files, jwilder-nginx-proxy

I have a web app (django served by uwsgi) and I am using nginx for proxying requests to specific containers.
Here is a relevant snippet from my default.conf.

```
upstream web.ubuntu.com {
server 172.18.0.9:8080;
}
server {
server_name web.ubuntu.com;
listen 80 ;
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
location / {
include uwsgi_params;
uwsgi_pass uwsgi://web.ubuntu.com;
}
}
```

Now I want the static files to be served from nginx rather than uwsgi workers.

So basically I want to add something like:

```
location /static/ {
autoindex on;
alias /staticfiles/;
}
```

to the automatically generated server block for the container.

I believe this should make nginx serve all requests to web.ubuntu.com/static/* from /staticfiles folder.

But since the configuration(default.conf) is generated automatically, I don't know how to add the above location to the server block dynamically :(

I think location block can't be outside a server block right and there can be only one server block per server?

so I don't know how to add the location block there unless I add dynamically to default.conf after nginx comes up and then reload it I guess.

I did go through https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy and I only see an example to actually change location settings per-host and default. But nothing about adding a new location altogether.

I already posted this in Q&A for jwilder/nginx-proxy and didn't get a response.

Please help me if there is a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This answer is based on this [comment](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy/issues/553#issuecomment-339457619) from the #553 issue discussion on the official [nginx-proxy](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy.git) repo. First, you have to create the `default_location` file with the static location:

```
location /static/ {
    alias /var/www/html/static/;
}
```

and save it, for example, into `nginx-proxy` folder in your project's root directory. Then, you have to add this file to `/etc/nginx/vhost.d` folder of the `jwilder/nginx-proxy` container. You can build a new image based on `jwilder/nginx-proxy` with this file being copied or you can mount it using `volumes` section. Also, you have to share static files between your `webapp` and `nginx-proxy` containers using a shared volume. As a result, your `docker-compose.yml` file will look something like this:

```
version: "3"

services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      - ./nginx-proxy/default_location:/etc/nginx/vhost.d/default_location
      - static:/var/www/html/static

  webapp:
    build: ./webapp
    expose:
      - 8080
    volumes:
      - static:/path/to/webapp/static
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=webapp.docker.localhost
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=8080
      - VIRTUAL_PROTO=uwsgi

volumes:
  static:
```

Now, the `server` block in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` will always include the static location:

```
server {
    server_name webapp.docker.localhost;
    listen 80 ;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass uwsgi://webapp.docker.localhost;
        include /etc/nginx/vhost.d/default_location;
    }
}
```

which will make Nginx serve static files for you.

Comment: Dockerfile example  
```FROM jwilder/nginx-proxy  

COPY default_location /etc/nginx/vhost.d/default_location```

You must set location witch you copy with filename, like in my example. And clear you docker volumes if you already tried create reverse proxy container!