# jwilder/nginx-proxy: serving static files for multiple apps - how to separate static files dir for different apps

Tags: docker, docker-compose, static-files, jwilder-nginx-proxy

I followed this question
[serving static files from jwilder/nginx-proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54571819/serving-static-files-from-jwilder-nginx-proxy)
to serve static files.

This works fine with one app with static files. I want to add a second app, which means I need to have a root directory for static files per app. Otherwise, there is the risk of name collisions.
Is there a way to specify the static files folder per app?

Maybe subfolders per app in the root directory would work as well, but there are apps where I cannot influence where they store their static files. So I don't see how this could work.

Comment: Why not create different docker containers for each App which serves the static files? Then you would have everything standard (make use of standard images). Nginx forwards static-file-requests for each App to its specific Container (pointed to by IP or domain in Nginx Proxyserver)

Answer (score 0):

to handle static files with multiple directories you can use this method

```
location /static/ {
  expires 30d;
  access_log off;
  try_files tmp/static/$uri tmp/static/$uri/ tmp/static2/$uri tmp/static2/$uri/;
}
```